# make active tab in show / hide script

Tags: jquery

I have got a js script of show / hide

html:

```
<div class="footernav">1111</div>

<div class="copy gutters hide">
    content1
</div>

<div class="footernav">2222</div>

<div class="copy gutters hide">
    content2
</div>

<div class="footernav">3333</div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){

$(".footernav").each(function(i,o){
  $(this).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div.copy:eq("+i+")").toggle().siblings("div.copy").hide();
  });
});

});
```

css:

```
.hide {display:none;}
.show {display:block;}
```

DEMO  : http://jsfiddle.net/kolxoznik1/DYbBe/

I need help with making active div. When div is active (opened) then div name (in example it is 1111 or 2222 or 3333 ... must have a style (like new color: red or bold)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `click` handler, either before or after toggling the selected *copy* div and hiding the other *copy* divs, you could toggle an *active* class on `this` and remove it from its *footernav* siblings:

```
$(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('div.footernav').removeClass('active');
```